# Making animations repeatable upon a .click event

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to fade out a series of divs which were appended in and animated twice.  I can do this, but I am stumped as to how to make it all repeatable.  The idea is that a parent div is clicked, 3 child divs are animated in, they fade out, and it all starts over when the parent div is clicked again.  Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
$('#work').click(function(){

    $('body').append('<a href="Portfolio/index_portfolio.html"><div id="portfolio"><p>portfolio</p></div></a>').done;
    $('body').append('<a href="Sketchbook/index_sketchbook.html"><div id="sketchbook"><p>sketchbook</p></div></a>').done;
    $('body').append('<a href="Art/index_art.html"><div id="art"><p>art</p></div></a>').done;

    $('#portfolio').animate({'margin': '120px 0px 0px 890px','opacity':.6}, 500, function(){
        $(this).mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).animate({'opacity':1}, 100, function(){});
        });
        $(this).mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).animate({'opacity':.6}, 100, function(){
        });
        });

        setTimeout (function(){
                $('#portfolio').fadeOut(200)
                }, 4000);
    });

    $('#sketchbook').animate({'margin': '120px 0px 0px 1045px', 'opacity':.6}, 550, function(){
        $(this).mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).animate({'opacity':1}, 100, function(){});
        });
        $(this).mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).animate({'opacity':.6}, 100, function(){});
        });
    });

    $('#art').animate({'margin': '120px 0px 0px 1200', 'opacity':'.6'}, 600, function(){
        $(this).mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).animate({'opacity':1}, 100, function(){});
        });
        $(this).mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).animate({'opacity':.6}, 100, function(){});
        });
    });

    $('#bio').animate({'margin': '120px 0px 0px 1045', 'opacity':'0'}, 600, function(){$(this).remove();});
    $('#blog').animate({'margin': '120px 0px 0px 1045', 'opacity':'0'}, 550, function(){$(this).remove();});
    $('#inspiration').animate({'margin': '120px 0px 0px 1045', 'opacity':'0'}, 500, function(){$(this).remove();});


    /*var timer;(document).mousemove(function(){
        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = 0;
            }

            $('#portfolio').fadein();
            timer = setTimeout (function(){
                $('#portfolio').hide(200)
                }, 300);
        });*/

    });
```

If there are amateurish mistakes here, just bear with me.  I'm pretty new to coding.  I've tried to use var timer, which I am previously unfamiliar with.  This was to no effect.

EDIT: I fixed this problem by appending a string in which all three sub-navigation divs are children of an invisible div, which I called "subnav". I positioned it so that it could constitute the relevant space for the menu;  the items animate away on .mouseleave.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.appendTo()` to append your new div to the body, and insert immediately the animation.
It should works.
Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
$('#work').click(function(){    
$('<a href="Portfolio/index_portfolio.html"><div id="portfolio"><p>portfolio</p></div></a>').appendTo('body').animate({'margin': '120px 0px 0px 890px','opacity':.6}, 500, function(){
            $(this).mouseenter(function(){
                $(this).animate({'opacity':1}, 100, function(){});
            });
            $(this).mouseleave(function(){
                $(this).animate({'opacity':.6}, 100, function(){
            });
            });

            setTimeout (function(){
                    $('#portfolio').fadeOut(200)
                    }, 4000);
        });

        $('<a href="Sketchbook/index_sketchbook.html"><div id="sketchbook"><p>sketchbook</p></div></a>').appendTo('body').animate({'margin': '120px 0px 0px 1045px', 'opacity':.6}, 550, function(){
            $(this).mouseenter(function(){
                $(this).animate({'opacity':1}, 100, function(){});
            });
            $(this).mouseleave(function(){
                $(this).animate({'opacity':.6}, 100, function(){});
            });
        });

        $('<a href="Art/index_art.html"><div id="art"><p>art</p></div></a>').appendTo('body').animate({'margin': '120px 0px 0px 1200', 'opacity':'.6'}, 600, function(){
            $(this).mouseenter(function(){
                $(this).animate({'opacity':1}, 100, function(){});
            });
            $(this).mouseleave(function(){
                $(this).animate({'opacity':.6}, 100, function(){});
            });
        });

        $('#bio').animate({'margin': '120px 0px 0px 1045', 'opacity':'0'}, 600, function(){$(this).remove();});
        $('#blog').animate({'margin': '120px 0px 0px 1045', 'opacity':'0'}, 550, function(){$(this).remove();});
        $('#inspiration').animate({'margin': '120px 0px 0px 1045', 'opacity':'0'}, 500, function(){$(this).remove();});


        /*var timer;(document).mousemove(function(){
            if (timer) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = 0;
                }

                $('#portfolio').fadein();
                timer = setTimeout (function(){
                    $('#portfolio').hide(200)
                    }, 300);
            });*/

        });
```

Comment: Your code doesn't animate correctly (not for me at least) and also generates an invalid HTML if `#work` is clicked more than once.

Comment: I'm not really having trouble appending the divs... I'm doing this because they don't need to be clickable before they are visible. I'm not really understanding how appending them differently would help me achieve a timeout/inactivity event.

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the links each time button is clicked. One way is remove them on each click if they are already present. Although this is not a good idea, but it does work.

**jQuery**

```
$('#work').click(function(){
    $('#portfolio').parent('a').remove();
    $('#sketchbook').parent('a').remove();
    $('#art').parent('a').remove();

    $('body').append('<a href="Portfolio/index_portfolio.html"><div id="portfolio"><p>portfolio</p></div></a>').done;
    $('body').append('<a href="Sketchbook/index_sketchbook.html"><div id="sketchbook"><p>sketchbook</p></div></a>').done;
    $('body').append('<a href="Art/index_art.html"><div id="art"><p>art</p></div></a>').done;

    $('#portfolio').animate({'margin': '120px 0px 0px 890px','opacity':.6}, 500, function(){
        $(this).mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).animate({'opacity':1}, 100, function(){});
        });
        $(this).mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).animate({'opacity':.6}, 100, function(){
            });
        });

        setTimeout (function(){
            $('#portfolio').fadeOut(200)
        }, 4000);
    });

    $('#sketchbook').animate({'margin': '120px 0px 0px 1045px', 'opacity':.6}, 550, function(){
        $(this).mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).animate({'opacity':1}, 100, function(){});
        });
        $(this).mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).animate({'opacity':.6}, 100, function(){});
        });
    });

    $('#art').animate({'margin': '120px 0px 0px 1200', 'opacity':'.6'}, 600, function(){
        $(this).mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).animate({'opacity':1}, 100, function(){});
        });
        $(this).mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).animate({'opacity':.6}, 100, function(){});
        });
    });

    $('#bio').animate({'margin': '120px 0px 0px 1045', 'opacity':'0'}, 600, function(){$(this).remove();});
    $('#blog').animate({'margin': '120px 0px 0px 1045', 'opacity':'0'}, 550, function(){$(this).remove();});
    $('#inspiration').animate({'margin': '120px 0px 0px 1045', 'opacity':'0'}, 500, function(){$(this).remove();});
});
```